# My gun only works horizontally, not vertically [GODOT]

Tags: rotation, godot, gdscript

So, My code currently only moves the gun horizontally, but not vertically. I cannot figure this out. Here is my code (Thanks!):

```
extends Position3D
onready var charCamera = get_parent()
##var direction = Camera.global_transform.basis.get_euler()

signal spawned(spawn)

export(PackedScene) var spawnling_scene

func _physics_process(_delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("leftClick"):
        spawn()

func spawn():
    var spawnling = spawnling_scene.instance()
    spawnling.linear_velocity = global_transform.basis.z * -100
    add_child(spawnling)
    spawnling.set_as_toplevel(true)
    emit_signal("spawned", spawnling)
    ##insert pause system
    return spawnling
```

Comment: The control for the direction is not here. How is the scene setup? I'm guessing it is on the parent `Node`. The `charCamera` implies it is a `Camera`. Is it first person? I also see that you have a commented line taking the Euler angles of the `Basis` of the `Camera`. If you want the direction from the `Camera`, you could the `Basis` from the `Camera` for the `linear_velocity`. Does that work for you? On that note: you can get the current camera from the `Viewport`: `get_viewport().get_camera()`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is first person.

Comment: worked instantly! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

For a first person game you probably want to shoot in the direction the camera is looking. You can get the current `Camera` from the `Viewport` using `get_viewport().get_camera()`.

*Be aware that you can change which `Camera` is `current`.*

And then, use the `Basis` from the `Camera` to set the direction of the `linear_velocity`:

```
var camera := get_viewport().get_camera()
rigid_body.linear_velocity = camera.global_transform.basis.z * -speed
```